# Missing partition ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

Tags: boot, boot-repair, boot-partition

I need help with a VM. I try to extend a partition with fdisk. After a reboot, I got this error:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Here you can find a pastebin from Boot-Repair: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/yYGhp8SCYx/

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================




Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

No OS to fix.

=================== /boot détecté. Veuillez vérifier les options.
Veuillez sauvegarder vos données avant cette opération.
adding: 20230807_175220/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175220/sda3/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175220/sda2/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175220/sda/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175220/sda/partition_table.dmp (deflated 45%)
adding: 20230807_175220/sda/current_mbr.img (deflated 100%)
adding: 20230807_175220/boot-repair.log (deflated 76%)
adding: 20230807_175452/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175452/sda3/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175452/sda2/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175452/sda/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175452/sda/partition_table.dmp (deflated 45%)
adding: 20230807_175452/sda/current_mbr.img (deflated 100%)
adding: 20230807_175452/boot-repair.log (deflated 80%)
adding: 20230807_175856/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175856/sda3/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175856/sda2/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175856/sda/ (stored 0%)
adding: 20230807_175856/sda/partition_table.dmp (deflated 45%)
adding: 20230807_175856/sda/current_mbr.img (deflated 100%)
adding: 20230807_175856/boot-repair.log (deflated 74%)
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the MBR.
Additional repair will be performed:  repair-filesystems


Force Unmount all blkid partitions (for fsck) except / /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home /opt /pas /proc /rofs /sys /tmp /usr /var

fsck -fyM /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2

fsck -fyM /dev/sda3
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda3

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or
e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sda3

Le démarrage de l'ordinateur a été correctement réparé.

Vous pouvez maintenant redémarrer votre ordinateur.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt2)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: SVGA II Adapter from VMware
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 6.00(4.6) from Phoenix Technologies LTD
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ng, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 130 GiB, 139586437120 bytes, 272629760 sectors
Disk identifier: FB92DA99-B888-48F8-AF24-2E0FF7F3C6C1
        Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sda1     2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
sda2     4096   2101247   2097152    1G Linux filesystem
sda3  2101248 272629726 270528479  129G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:140GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:VMware Virtual disk:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:1076MB:1074MB:ext4::;
3:1076MB:140GB:139GB:::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1                                               7b052058-5801-4672-88ec-2ccd7e989365                          
├─sda2 ext4     0f777c6b-1522-4976-bdde-6b67139d66ff 9b0bca3d-e67c-43c4-a513-3859536e4bf3                          
└─sda3                                               b248fd45-4ec9-cf4c-b8a0-dbb38fafcb27                          

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                           Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                 698.1M  21% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


======================== sda2/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

Ubuntu   b24ff2a2-4f6a-4999-be85-2388e7797e0f
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-155-generic   b24ff2a2-4f6a-4999-be85-2388e7797e0f
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-150-generic   b24ff2a2-4f6a-4999-be85-2388e7797e0f
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0,138713837 = 0,148942848    grub/grub.cfg                                  1
   0,232742310 = 0,249905152    grub/i386-pc/core.img                          1
   0,405387878 = 0,435281920    vmlinuz                                        1
   0,194385529 = 0,208719872    vmlinuz-5.4.0-150-generic                      1
   0,405387878 = 0,435281920    vmlinuz-5.4.0-155-generic                      1
   0,194385529 = 0,208719872    vmlinuz.old                                    1
   0,860034943 = 0,923455488    initrd.img                                     1
   0,705074310 = 0,757067776    initrd.img-5.4.0-150-generic                   3
   0,860034943 = 0,923455488    initrd.img-5.4.0-155-generic                   1
   0,705074310 = 0,757067776    initrd.img.old                                 3
```

Is it possible to "recreate" ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv?

Comment: Snce we don't know what exactly you did it's hard to tell if this is fixable or not. `fdisk` only manipulates the partition table, so your data must still be there on the disk. `boot-repair` does't help anything in such a case. Your best bet is [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download), boot your installer in the VM, try without installing, then `sudo apt install testdisk` and `sudo testdisk`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk_doc/). If there are very valuable data on the disk, you may want to backup the whole disk first!

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. I managed to get back on my system but my sda3 partition is missing.

Comment: Your boot-info-summary shows clearly a `sda3`-partition, so how is it missing? I think that's the partition you edited in a wrong way since it doesn't show a file system. How can you be back on your system if this partition is missing? Doesn't make sense to me. as I said, `testdisk` is the tool for such things.